# Python: Efficiency of netCDF4 vs ncks?

Tags: performance, file-io, system-calls, netcdf4

Let's say I have a large .nc4 file I am trying to read into my Python script. I'm trying to compare two ways of doing so.

1. using an ncks binary (finds data within a .nc4 file)

   import os

   os.popen("ncks file").read()
2. using the netCDF4 library

   import netCDF4

   netCDF4.Dataset("file")

Basically, I can get the same results from either method, but I'm curious as to what is fundamentally different about the two methods.  I see that I'm making a system call in the first method. But since they are both reading from a file, does that mean that the netCDF4 library is a wrapper for the same system call? Is one more efficient than the other (my initial tests seem to suggest netCDF4 library is faster)?

Thanks.